# Why pattern based programming in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, iterator

Wondering why C# is moving towards more pattern based programming rather than conventional ways.

Ex. The `foreach` statement expects that the loop source to have a magic method called `GetEnumerator` which returns an object which has a few more magic methods like `MoveNext` and `Current`, but they don't mandate any specific interface? C# could have mandated that a class to be used in `foreach` should implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` as it does for the`using` statement in that it expects an object to be used in `using` statement to implement the `IDisposable` interface.

Also, I see a similar trend with `async`/`await` keywords as well....

Of course there must be a good reason for that, but it seems a little odd for me to understand the reason why does compiler/CLR requires "magic methods" rather than relying on interfaces.

Comment: hi Andrew Barber, may I understand the reason why you have decided to put the question on hold? I tried to search for an answer already but could not find it.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano You're wrong. You can iterate over your class even when it does not implement `IEnumerable` nor `IEnumerable<T>` as long as there is public `GetEnumerator` method which returns type with `MoveNext` method and `Current` property available.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Big lol here. I'm baffled, I didn't know that, and would have never said it, especially because the MSDN page about `foreach` explicitly talks about the interfaces!

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Check the 2003 version. It's written there.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx This explains the need for magic methods behind async/await keywords. Thanks for your answer, MarcinJuraszek

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***`foreach`***

I would say it's both about performance and compatibility

- If you had chosen `foreach` to use `IEnumerable` it would have made all generic
  collections iteration very slow for value-types `T` (because of
  boxing/unboxing).
- If you had chosen to use `IEnumerable<T>` iterating over `ArrayList` and
  all non-generic collections from early .NET version would have not been
  possible.

I think the design decision was good. When `foreach` was introduced (.NET 1.1) there was nothing about generics in .NET (they were introduced in .NET 2.0). Choosing `IEnumerable` as a source of `foreach` enumeration would make using it with generic collections poor or would require a radical change. I guess designers already knew that they were going to introduce generics not that long time later.

Additionaly, declaring it as *use `IEnumerable<T>` when it's available or `IEnumerable` when it's not* is not much different then *use available `GetEnumerator` method or do not compile when it's not available*, is it?

*update*

As @mikez mentioned in comments, there is one more advantage. When you don't expect `GetEnumerator` to return `IEnumerator`/`IEnumerator<T>` you can return `struct` and don't worry about boxing when the enumerator is used by loop.

***LINQ***

The same *magic methods* situation occurs when you use LINQ and syntax based queries. When you write

```
var results = from item in source
              where item != "test"
              select item.ToLower();
```

it's transformed by compiler into

```
var results = source.Where(x => x != "test")
                    .Select(x => x.ToLower());
```

And because that code would work no matter what interface `source` implement the same applies to syntax-based query. As long as after transforming it to method-based query every method call can be properly assigned by compiler everything is OK.

***async/await***

I'm not that sure but think the same thing applies to `async`/`await`. When you use these keywords compiler generates a bunch of code for yourself, which is then compiled as if you'd written the code by yourself. And as long as code made by that transformation can be compiled everything is OK.

Comment: `async`/`await` does do some matching of members based on patterns when you want to implement a custom awaiter. It is similar in to `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator`. See section 7.7.7 of the C# 5 specification.

Comment: @mikez I don't say it doesn't. As long as after `async`/`await` is transformed into proper state machine all method calls can be made (mean you satisfy the methods matching) everything is compiled just fine.

Comment: I couldn't tell what you meant by "I'm not sure but think the same thing applies". I thought you were unsure that pattern matching was used.

Comment: @mikez I know it works that way, I'm not sure what's the reason.

Comment: I think one thing worth mentioning is that it allows you to use a value type to implement the interfaces (e.g. IEnumerator) without causing the "enumerator" type itself to be boxed. This is what `List<T>` does.